# How to publish xUnit and jUnit test results to gitlab

Tags: junit, jenkins-pipeline, gitlab-ci, xunit, gitlab-api

I have a jenkins pipeline with test stage that triggered via hook on gitlab. Is there any way to publish test results under gitlab for the triggered build?

Thank you

Answer (score -1):

When looking at a problem like this I typically:

1. Check the : [Jenkins Pipeline Steps Reference](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/) - there are gitlab related steps but I don't see anything about JUnit results
2. Check the Vendor's documentation [GitLab's page on JUnit results](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/junit_test_reports.html) - it looks like you have to use their *runner* to get JUnit results - you could investigate whether or not you can run this from your pipeline
3. Look to see if there is a REST api you can use. The [Http Request Plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/http_request/) is really easy to use to talk to various external servers - if GitLab has an API that you can call you may be able to implement it this way.